# My PC is creating multiple sessions on websites I log into?

Tags: session, connection, browser

The administrator of one of the online games i regularly play recently brought to my attention that whenever i log on, multiple sessions of my account are created. Until yesterday this was not a problem for either myself nor their website. Yesterday the site was acting extremely slow on my computer, pages would not fully load and when they did load it took a very long time for them to do so. I notified the admin and he replied saying that i was using their site with about 300 sessions per minute.

Apparently I am the only one on the site that is having this problem. I have been playing the game for a long time and this has never happened. The site also show your last 3 loggin's IP address and i have noticed that all my 3 login IPs are always different.

If you have any idea of what is happening or how to fix it please let me know so i can contact the administrator. If you need to know the website is: http://www.businessgame.be/

Comment: Not really a programming question. However, what have you tried? Have you tried another browser (IE/FF/Chrome/Opera)? Have you tried another PC? Are you on wireless? Have you tried being on WLAN/LAN or directly attaching your PC to the modem? Have you installed anything special ('helper' plugins, debug plugins, fiddler, firewalls, packet sniffers, ...)? Have you tried changing your password? Clearing your cookies? Are you using a proxy? Should you?

Comment: it might be possible the site working on cookies, try to set your browser setting to clear all cookies when you close the browser and do not remember any password from any site.

Comment: Ive tried anouther browser (IE) no difference there, i dont have any proxies and im not on wireless. No plugins either. Im not sure clearing my cookies will help!

Comment: @Michael, I've learned not to make assumptions like that.  I once discovered an issue with my CD burner was caused by my video card.  I'm still surprised by what causes some computer issues.

Comment: Thanx XD. I think what might be the problem is that i used to work on my XP partition where i had a static IP (i think) and now im working on my WIn7 partition where it auto detects. Could that cause this problem?